# No. of ways to arrange a duplicated list of numbers so that a copy of the list appears in order but not necessarily together

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I was making combinatorics exercises for some students when I stumped myself with a question I came up with.

**Question**

Bob has ten blue counters, labelled 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. If he rearranges all ten randomly in a line, how many different arrangements include a subsequence of five counters that read 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in that order (but not necessarily together)?

For example, **1**, 3, **2**, 5, 1, 4, **3**, **4**, **5**, 2 would satisfy the conditions.

**So what have I tried?**

I tried simplifying the problem to:

- two counters (1, 1) in which the number of ways the subsequence 1 appears somewhere is (trivially) 1.
- four counters (1, 2, 1, 2) in which the number of ways the subsequence 1, 2 appears somewhere is 5.
- six counters (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3) in which the number of ways the subsequence 1, 2, 3 appears somewhere is 47. I verified this in two ways. Firstly, I wrote out all 90 cases and counted manually. Then, I realised that any case where the subsequence 1, 2, 3 appears in order has the subsequence 1, 2 appearing in order. So, any solution to the 6-counter problem is simply a solution to the 4-counter problem, plus two carefully-positioned 3s. This broke the question into 5 cases which were simpler to exhaust.

For the question itself, I know the answer is lower than $10P5$.
$10P5$ is the answer to the following method: Given ten positions in a line, pick five to permute (i.e, place the counters 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 on, in a random order). Then place the remaining counters 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in that order in the remaining positions.

However, this grossly overcounts many cases. I think it overcounts each time a case has multiple subsequences of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. For example, the case of 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 is counted (I think) $2^5 = 32$ times. The case of **1**, 2, 4, 2, **3**, **4**, 3, 5, 5, 1 is counted four times. This is because every subsequence of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 must include the bolded 1, 3 and 4, but there are two options for the 2s and two options for the 5s. So there are four subsequences of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in this case.

As a side note, is there a way to generalise this for $2n$ counters, labelled 1 through $n$ twice over?

Comment: @C2H6O do you know principle of inclusion-exclusion ?

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish I don't think Inclusion-Exclusion is so easy here.  See my comment following your answer.

Comment: I think you are looking for https://oeis.org/A006902

Comment: A related (harder) problem: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122422/permutations-with-given-longest-increasing-subsequence

Comment: Consider five barrels of water $-$ numbered $1,2,3,4,5-$ each of which contains $2$ fish. Randomly pick and shoot at one of the five barrels over and over (in a memoryless way) until no fish are left. What is the probability that all fish from barrel $i$ are killed before barrel $i+1$ for all $i$? I believe this probability times $ \frac{5!}{2^5}$ will be your answer. I tried to use recursion to get this probability, but I'm having trouble defining the states @lulu

Comment: Have you looked at that link I posted, C2H?

Comment: Well? Have you?

Answer (score 0):

Found and corrected the programming error.  I was basing duplicate records on Java's int (i.e. integer) data type, not realizing that Java's MAX_INTEGER $~= \left[ ~2^{31} ~\right] - 1.$

I converted to Java's Long data type and now obtain the result $~11389,~$ that matches
[oeis.org/A006902](https://oeis.org/A006902) .

---

I wrote a Java program to attack the case of 10 counters, labeled 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5.  The java program returned a count of 6469, out of 30240 possible.  I will describe the pseudocode so that anyone can write their own program, to verify the results.

Unfortunately, I am unable to conjure any analytical results.

---

$\underline{\text{Pseudocode}}$

First, I created a two dimension array of integers, with dimensions 120 x 5.  Denote this array as arrFactorial.

Each element of arrFactorial is an array of 5 integers.  Each array is a permutation of the elements in the set {1,2,3,4,5}, and each array is distinct from all of the other arrays (i.e. elements) in arrFactorial.  120 represents the number of ways of permuting the elements in the set {1,2,3,4,5}.

Then, I created a 5-nested loop, using the variables a,b,c,d,e:

- a looped from 0 through 5.
- b looped from (a+1) through 6.
- c looped from (b+1) through 7.
- d looped from (c+1) through 8.
- e looped from (d+1) through 9.

The variables a,b,c,d,e represent the 0-based positions that will be assigned in a constructed 10 digit array of integers, where :

- a represents the position where a 1 will be placed.
- b represents the position where a 2 will be placed.
- c represents the position where a 3 will be placed.
- d represents the position where a 4 will be placed.
- e represents the position where a 5 will be placed.

So, I ended up with $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{5} = 252~$ partially constructed  arrays, where each array had 10 positions, and 5 of those positions had been filled in.

Note that from any sequence of 10 integers from the set {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5}, if the sequence contains a strictly ascending subsequence of 5 elements, then the sequence will have to correspond to at least one of the 252 partially constructed sequences that I created.

---

$\underline{\text{For each of the 252 partially constructed sequences}}:$

I used the arrFactorial array to create 120 distinct 10 digit arrays as follows:

Looking at the elements in arrFactorial, one at a time, I used each element, which was a distinct permutation of the set {1,2,3,4,5}, to determine which integer would be placed in the first empty slot in the constructed sequence, which integer would be placed in the second empty slot in the constructed sequence, and so forth.

For example, suppose:

```
a,b,c,d,e = 1,3,5,7,9 respectively.
So, the partially constructed array looks like
_1_2_3_4_5
Suppose futher that the specific arrFactorial element
being used is 
34512
Then, this combination of the (a,b,c,d,e) ordered set
and the specific arrFactorial element creates the 
sequence
3142531425
```

As expected, this resulted in $~120 \times 252~$ 10-digit sequences, which contained all of the satisfying sequences, but where some of the sequences were duplicated.

I then used Java's HashSet data type, which features an add method.  When you add an element to the HashSet, it will automatically return false and reject the element, if the element represents a duplicate record.

I constructed the corresponding hashcode for each sequence that was being added so that (for example)

```
the sequence 
3 1 4 2 5 3 1 4 2 5
would be assigned the hashcode of 
3142531425.
```

This implies that each element in the HashSet must represent a distinct array of 10 integers.

**Edit**
Initially, my program returned an erroneous result.

Some of the 10 digit sequences had id's greater than Java's MAX_INTEGER $~= \left[ ~2^{31} ~\right] - 1.$

This caused some of the distinct records to be erroneously rejected as duplicate records, by Java's HashSet datatype.

Subsequently, I changed my code to store the id as a long (Java) data type, rather than an int data type.

The program now returns a value of $~11389,~$ that matches
[oeis.org/A006902](https://oeis.org/A006902) .